# Append two Pandas series to a dataframe by columns with a Loop

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe and two Pandas Series ac and cc, i want to append this two series as column with a loop. But the problem is that my dataframe has a time index and Series as integer

```
A='a'

cc  = pd.Series(np.zeros(len(A)*20))
ac  = pd.Series(np.random.randn(10))

index = pd.date_range(start=pd.datetime(2017, 1,1), end=pd.datetime(2017, 1, 2), freq='1h')

df = pd.DataFrame(index=index)
```

I already had an answer to my question but without a loop [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44339150/append-two-pandas-series-to-a-dataframe-by-columns?noredirect=1#comment75683049_44339150)

Now, i need to add a loop but i got an error in the keys :

```
az = [cc, ac]

for i in az:
    df.join(
            pd.concat(
            [pd.Series(s.values, index[:len(s)]) for s in [i]],
            axis=1, keys=[i]
           )
         )

ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), ,a.any() or a.all().
```

I tried with `keys = [i.all ()]`, I have the correct answer except that instead of the columns names I have true and false.

The final result should be like this :

```
                     cc    ac   
2017-01-01 00:00:00   1    0.247043 
2017-01-01 01:00:00   1    -0.324868 
2017-01-01 02:00:00   1    -0.004868
2017-01-01 03:00:00   1    0.047043 
2017-01-01 04:00:00   1    -0.447043 
2017-01-01 05:00:00 NaN    NaN 
...                 ...    ...
```

Comment: I can't tell exactly what you want the result to look like.  Do you want it to be exactly as your other question's result?  Just produced in a loop?

Comment: Yes that's all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a list of tuples where the first element is the column name and the second is the series itself.

```
az = [('cc', cc), ('ac', ac)]

for c, s in az:
    df[c] = pd.Series(s.values, index[:len(s)])

                      cc        ac
2017-01-01 00:00:00  0.0  2.062265
2017-01-01 01:00:00  0.0 -0.225066
2017-01-01 02:00:00  0.0 -1.698330
2017-01-01 03:00:00  0.0 -1.068081
2017-01-01 04:00:00  0.0  0.142956
2017-01-01 05:00:00  0.0 -1.244232
2017-01-01 06:00:00  0.0 -1.072311
2017-01-01 07:00:00  0.0  0.242069
2017-01-01 08:00:00  0.0  0.120093
2017-01-01 09:00:00  0.0 -0.335500
2017-01-01 10:00:00  0.0       NaN
2017-01-01 11:00:00  0.0       NaN
2017-01-01 12:00:00  0.0       NaN
2017-01-01 13:00:00  0.0       NaN
2017-01-01 14:00:00  0.0       NaN
2017-01-01 15:00:00  0.0       NaN
2017-01-01 16:00:00  0.0       NaN
2017-01-01 17:00:00  0.0       NaN
2017-01-01 18:00:00  0.0       NaN
2017-01-01 19:00:00  0.0       NaN
2017-01-01 20:00:00  NaN       NaN
2017-01-01 21:00:00  NaN       NaN
2017-01-01 22:00:00  NaN       NaN
2017-01-01 23:00:00  NaN       NaN
2017-01-02 00:00:00  NaN       NaN
```

Comment: Thanks a lot @piRSquared.